# How to find out the date of second Monday of each month of given year?

Tags: ruby

My customer has an event each second Monday of each month.

I need to mark them with red in calendar.

How do i "cleanly" find out the date of that Mondays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my version.

If the eighth of the month is a Monday, then it is the second Monday. If it is not a Monday, then how many days until the next Monday?

```
oct_2012 = Date.new 2012, 10, 8
oct_2012.wday   # => 1, We're done!

nov_2012 = Date.new 2012, 11, 8
nov_2012.wday   # => 4
nov_2012 + (8 - nov_2012.wday)  # => 2012-11-12
```

Does that help?

### Edit

Easier version: Just add and be done. This algorithm works even if the month starts on a Monday.

```
oct_2012 = Date.new 2012, 10, 1
oct_2012 + (8 - oct_2012.wday)  # => 2012-10-08

nov_2012 = Date.new 2012, 11, 1
nov_2012 + (8 - nov_2012.wday)  # => 2012-11-12
```

One rule and done!

Comment: seems to work, thanks. would be nice to have a place to drop Ruby snippets and see them running, like on jsfiddle

Comment: sure, for me too, but i'm tired of copy/paste :)

Comment: @PaulMiller I have used [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) before. It has worked well for me.

Comment: thanks, seems to work, though slow. and it looks too 90ish with tones of annoying ad

Comment: It's not slow to find a single date. How many months are you evaluating at once? And I'm not sure what you mean by "looks 90ish".

Answer (score 0):

You second Monday will always fall within the 8th and 14th of each month.